# Fetch Values from SimpleAdapter to array[]

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to transfer values from `SimpleAdapter` to `array[]`. I am getting values in `SimpleAdapter` from `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` and want to pass these values from `SimpleAdapter` to `array[]`.

```
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,R.layout.list_item,new String[] {android_H_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.name});

String[] hospFields = //want to get values here from adapter
```

Comment: Any particular reason to avoid contactList's toArray method?

Comment: You should define "values"

Comment: i tried this but dun know y it gives an error.                 for(int x = 0; x <= contactList.size(); x++)
{
 hospFields[x] = contactList.get(x).get(android_H_NAME);
}

Comment: u want to implement setOnItemClickListener too??

Comment: yeah i want to setOnItemClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to access the data directly, but you can use (in general):

```
Object[] o = new Object[adapter.getCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    o[i] = adapter.getItem(i);
}
```

to create a copy of your Adapter data. If you want just to extract specific values use:

```
String[] hospFields = new String[adapter.getCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> rowData = adapter.getItem(i); //gets HashMap of a specific row
    String name = rowData.get("name"); //gets the field name of that row
    hospFields[i] = name; // copies field into your array
}
```

Comment: then how will i transfer from o to String[] hospFields

Comment: for(i=0;i<o;i++){hospFields[i] =(String) o[i];}  this will be the way ?

Comment: check edited answer.. if this wont work for you then try (String)adapter.getItem(i) instead of adapter.getItem(i).toString()

Comment: Thanks every one who give their time to help my issue

Comment: If your issue is solved then please accept this as an answer. This will help others who might be facing same issue

Comment: @silwa your suggested answer is giving whole value inside adapter like  id, name, address.. but what i need is to fill array just with name

Comment: @silwa edited answer is giving me.. {id=1,name=ali,adress=yyy}{id=2,name=babar,adress=yyy}{id=1,name=john,adress=yyy} but what i need is to fill array like {name=ali,name=baber,name=john}

Comment: That's because you get an instance of HashMap with `getItem`. That's why I wrote `Object[] o` in the original answer to avoid confusion since you can use different data container with an adapter, especially if you use your own adapters. If you write `adapter.getItem(i).toString()` you get a String reprasentation of your HashMap, since `getItem(i)` gives you a HashMap holding the data of row `i`. You should work on your Java basics! See updated answer. This one should give you a copy of all names in your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Modify and use this:

```
 ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
    try {
        listItems
                .add(result.getJSONObject(i)
                        .getString(BsharpConstant.NAME_CONSTANT)
                        .toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Inside oncreate method:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idOfUrView);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
 ActivityName.this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
             list.setOnItemClickListener(this);//if u need this until not required
```

Use this want to stores the value in item click:

```
 @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
  long id) {
 String clickedItemName = (String) listOfProductsCategory
    .getItemAtPosition(position);
   int clickedItemId = (int) listOfProductsCategory
    .getItemIdAtPosition(position);
 // implement your login to store the value
     //by using for loop listItems[i] ,i++
   Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),
       "Custom text : " + clickedItemName,
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //call your method if u want
```

}